# How to make multiple DROP-shadow?

Tags: css, css-filters

i want make two shadows with dropshadow for the div backgroundimage.
This wont work:

```
-webkit-filter:drop-shadow(3px 3px 5px #000000, 2px 2px 2px #ffcc00);
filter:drop-shadow(3px 3px 5px #000000, 2px 2px 2px #ffcc00);
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The `filter` property accepts multiple filters, so you can repeat `drop-shadow`:

```css
filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 5px #000000) drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px #ffcc00);
```

```css
.gray {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 5px #000000);
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 5px #000000);
}
.yellow {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px #ffcc00);
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px #ffcc00);
}
.gray-yellow {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 5px #000000) drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px #ffcc00);
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 5px #000000) drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px #ffcc00);
}
```

```html
<span class="gray">Hello world</span>
+ <span class="yellow">Hello world</span>
= <span class="gray-yellow">Hello world</span>
```

Comment: Must be really subtle because it's doing nothing in Chrome

Comment: `-webkit-filter` @Paulie_D

Comment: @Paulie_D Chrome needs a vendor prefix. I have included it in the snippet.

Comment: But you have to switch the first drop-shadow with the second, because the smaller one has to be at the frist place!

Comment: be careful, 2nd shadow is applied on first as you can see on the example: https://codepen.io/yukulele/pen/MrNJja

Comment: There is no need for -webkit- prefix for a long time already. Check [CanIUse](https://www.caniuse.com/?search=drop-shadow). It works everywhere that matter for a vast majority of us. The difference is definitely subtle though.

Comment: I can confirm this works fine in 2021 in chrome

Answer (score 1):

Separate each filter by a space between them:

```
filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 8px #7f6400 ) drop-shadow(0px 0px 8px #7f6400 )
```